# Rectangle ArgumentOutOfRangeException Per-Pixel Collision

Tags: c#, exception

I've been trying to solve this problem but I really can't see what's wrong with the code. It's exactly the same as my other rectangles but it won't work.

Working Code: Everything in here works fine (more or less)

```
private void UpdateCollision()
    {
        // Uses built in rectangle intersect function to determine overlapping
        Rectangle rectangle1;
        Rectangle rectangle2;
        Rectangle rectangle3;

        // Creates 1 rectangle for player
        rectangle1 = new Rectangle((int)player.Position.X, (int)player.Position.Y, player.Width, player.Height);

        // Sets collision btw objs
        for (int i = 0; i < enemies.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < enemies2.Count; j++)
            {
                rectangle2 = new Rectangle((int)enemies[i].Position.X, (int)enemies[i].Position.Y, enemies[i].Width, enemies[i].Height);
                rectangle3 = new Rectangle((int)enemies2[j].Position.X, (int)enemies2[j].Position.Y, enemies2[j].Width, enemies2[j].Height);

                // Determines collision
                if (IntersectPixels(rectangle1, playerTextureData, rectangle2, enemyTextureData) && player.PlayerAnimation.Active == true)
                {
                    player.Health -= enemies[i].Damage;
                    enemies[i].Health = 0;

                    if (player.Health == 0)
                        AddMyExplosion(player.Position);
                }

                if (IntersectPixels(rectangle1, playerTextureData, rectangle3, enemy2TextureData) && player.PlayerAnimation.Active == true)
                {
                    player.Health -= enemies2[j].Damage;
                    enemies2[j].Health = 0;

                    if (player.Health == 0)
                        AddMyExplosion(player.Position);
                }
            }
        }
```

Non-working Code: The line where the exception pops up is where rectangle3 is defined

```
// Proj obj collision
        for (int i = 0; i < projectiles.Count; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < enemies.Count; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < enemies2.Count; k++)
                {

                    // Creates col det rectangles
                    rectangle1 = new Rectangle((int)projectiles[i].Position.X - projectiles[i].Width / 2, (int)projectiles[i].Position.Y - projectiles[i].Height / 2, projectiles[i].Width, projectiles[i].Height);
                    rectangle2 = new Rectangle((int)enemies[j].Position.X - enemies[j].Width / 2, (int)enemies[j].Position.Y - enemies[j].Height / 2, enemies[j].Width, enemies[j].Height);
                    rectangle3 = new Rectangle((int)enemies2[k].Position.X - enemies2[k].Width / 2, (int)enemies[k].Position.Y - enemies2[k].Height / 2, enemies2[k].Width, enemies2[k].Height);
                    //Rectangle 3 is not working//

                    // Determines col
                    if (IntersectPixels(rectangle1, projectileTextureData, rectangle2, enemyTextureData))
                    {
                        enemies[j].Health -= projectiles[i].Damage;
                        AddImpact(projectiles[i].Position);
                        impactSound.Play();
                        projectiles[i].Active = false;
                    }

                    if (IntersectPixels(rectangle1, projectileTextureData, rectangle3, enemy2TextureData))
                    {
                        enemies2[j].Health -= projectiles[i].Damage;
                        AddImpact(projectiles[i].Position);
                        impactSound.Play();
                        projectiles[i].Active = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So if anyone could help me solve this I would be very grateful.

Comment: Please tell us what is not working. Also, please shorten the code.

Comment: In that failing line shouldn't (int)enemies[k].Position.Y be (int)enemies2[k].Position.Y ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo. Change this line:

```
rectangle3 = new Rectangle((int)enemies2[k].Position.X - enemies2[k].Width / 2, (int)enemies[k].Position.Y - enemies2[k].Height / 2, enemies2[k].Width, enemies2[k].Height);
```

to this:

```
rectangle3 = new Rectangle((int)enemies2[k].Position.X - enemies2[k].Width / 2, (int)enemies2[k].Position.Y - enemies2[k].Height / 2, enemies2[k].Width, enemies2[k].Height);
```

Comment: Taking the time to read and verify all that code makes you a hero.

Comment: I've actually always been pretty good at spotting minor copy/paste errors like this - I think it's analogous to how in WWI they would send color-blind men up in observation planes, because they could easily spot colored camouflage.